# Order result from Facebook Graph API by time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with the Facebook API. The problem i am facing since facebook change to new API version which is does not support FQL anymore and i am unable to sort the result by **created_time** which is I don't have any problem when using FQL because can order by using FQL. This is my graph API code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/MYFBID/feed?since=TIMESTAMP&access_token=XXX
```

is there any possible way to sort the result order by **created_time**

Answer (score 0):

as per told [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed) you can use the stream_filter's filters but specifying it in the "filter" param.

Good. As per i can understand, you should be able to query using something like:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/MYFBID/feed?filter=&access_token=XXX

Anyway i can't find "since" in the stream_filter's filters specs, so i think you can't filter using the since keyword, but i may be wrong, try experimenting... i'll do it by myself, but i use the new SDK 4.x in my portal, so it may be very different from your code.

Hope this can help in some way.
Bye! :-)

Comment: thanks for your response. FYI, since can use. and i successfully use that 'since' that is to show the result that only from the specific time that i need. by using since. can u please show me how to order the output result by created time DESC for example. Tq